# Sliding to Rolling

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

In a problem where a sphere is initially sliding and then begins to roll after having travelled some distance. The thing that confused me is that the work done by friction on the sphere is not simply equal to ($\mu mg \times d$) ( where $\mu$ = coefficient of friction and $d$= distance traversed before rolling) but is something else. The book mentions that it is because friction does not act over distance '$d$'. Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: If you zoom in at a microscopic level,  the spheres bottom surface is not sliding along the ground. When an object rolls it acts like a giant gear with the surface it is on. Work due to friction occurs when there is sliding.

Comment: When the sphere begins to roll it gains rotational energy as well, at that point there is no more losses to friction (unless they give you some rolling friction coefficient). E=0.5 x Inertia(rotational) x omega squared.

Answer (score -1):

> The book mentions that it is because friction does not act over
>   distance '$d$'

But even if it was true, how would you know $d$?

Before friction started to act the sphere's kinetic energy would be:

$$K_0=\frac12 mv_0^2+\frac12 I\omega_0^2$$

Now friction sets in and causes a torque:
$$\tau=I\dot{\omega}$$
$$-\mu mgR=I\dot{\omega}$$
So that:
$$\omega(t)=\omega_0-\frac{\mu mgR}{I}t$$

The friction also affects translation:
$$F=-\mu mg=m\dot{v}$$
$$v(t)=v_0-\mu gt$$

At some point:
$$v(t)=\omega(t)R$$
$$\Rightarrow v_0-\mu gt=\omega_0 R-\frac{\mu mgR^2}{I}t$$

Extract $t$ from there and insert it in the time evolutions to get $v(t)$  and $\omega(t)$.

Then calculate $K(t)$ as:

$$K(t)=\frac12 mv(t)^2+\frac12 I\omega(t)^2$$

The difference $K_0-K(t)$ is of course the friction energy.

Comment: I already calculated "d" as follows ;

Comment: First using angular momentum i calculated the speed  of CM after rolling starts. Initial speed is given as V_0. Acceleration is negative mu times g .

Comment: From these i calculated "d" And also time it takes to reach the state of rolling. I think the point is that before rolling kicks in the bottom contact point is not moving at the same speed as that of CM (not that after rolling starts, it does) because the sphere is rotating too ( not purely rolling therefore velocity of bottom point is not zero but is equal to velocity of CM minus Rw, due to rotation aboht centre of mass). Therefore, it obviously travels less distance than CM. But i am not sure whether this reasoning is correct or not.

Comment: *But i am not sure whether this reasoning is correct or not.* I believe your reasoning indeed correct.